# CMake Error while configuring CUDA with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ubuntu-14.04, nvcc

I have OpenCV 3.0 completely installed and configured on Ubuntu 14.04. Now, I am trying to configure CUDA on OpenCV but when I type make command it gives an error about NCVPyramid files. How can I solve that problem about the NCVPyramid?
Here are the commands I used:

```
      ~/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/build$ cmake -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH-TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_VTK=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_JPEG=ON -D BUILD_PNG=ON -D BUILD_JASPER=ON -D BUILD_ZLIB=ON -D WITH_JPEG=ON -D WITH_PNG=ON -D WITH_JASPER=ON -D WITH_ZLIB=ON -D WITH_OPENEXR=ON ..

      ~/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/build$ make -j
```

The error is below:

> [ 47%] Built target opencv_cudabgsegm
>   [ 47%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/cuda_perf.cpp.o
>   [ 47%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_NCVPyramid.cu.o
>   In file included from /home/asgundogdu/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/modules/cudalegacy/src/cuda/NCVPyramid.cu:52:0:
>   /home/asgundogdu/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/modules/cudalegacy/src/cuda/NCVPixelOperations.hpp:48:19: fatal error: NCV.hpp: No such file or directory
>    #include "NCV.hpp"
>                      ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_NCVPyramid.cu.o.cmake:208 (message):
>     Error generating
>     /home/asgundogdu/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0-alpha/build/modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_NCVPyramid.cu.o
>
> make[2]: *** [modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_NCVPyramid.cu.o] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [modules/cudalegacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudalegacy.dir/all] Error 2

Process finishes by this error:

> [ 52%] Built target opencv_calib3d
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this problem too. I ultimately gave up and set WITH_CUDA=OFF. I will switch it back on if somebody finds a solution.